# Mageto2 : how to create a cms page and get complete url for the same ?

Tags: magento2, base-url, geturl

I want to get the complete url of specific page(CMS). How did we get a custom URL link in Magneto2 suppose CMS page is 'about-us'?

Comment: U need to create custom router

Comment: What are you trying to do? "create custom link" and "return link through rest api" are two completely different things. Please explain in more detail, otherwise you won't get useful answers (as you probably noticed by now)

Answer (score 2):

Define constructor of your class here I am creating a class in model
path: PackageName/ModuleName/Model/Test.php and
add the following code

```
 public function __construct(
    \Ipragmatech\Customurls\Helper\Data $helper,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
){
    $this->_helper = $helper;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

Create a function to return url :-

```
public function getAboutusUrl(){

        $aboutUs = "about-us";
        //or $aboutUs = "help/aboutus"
        $aboutUsUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl($aboutUs);

        return $aboutUsUrl;
    }
```

**Result**:- this will return url as : http://magentotest.com/about-us/

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained which class you were injecting and which model you were injecting it into